# Unity 3D: How could i store and replace a prefab from a grid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am creating a video game like [Crypt of the necrodancer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HiQUw5Np8o) and i am blocked when i want to generate a map
my idea was simple :
make a grid system and replace some tiles to have specific tiles (obstacle, wall...) but i don't know how i should store the information to replace my tile.

I based my grid generation map from [Sebastian Lague](https://github.com/SebLague/Create-a-Game-Source/blob/master/Episode%2008/MapGenerator.cs) tutorial

i would like to replace in the inspector my tiles

as far as i am, i've found a script for replacing some tiles by another but i can't save it...
Here is the script for replacing stuff

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class ReplaceWithPrefab : EditorWindow
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;

    [MenuItem("Tools/Replace With Prefab")]
    static void CreateReplaceWithPrefab()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow<ReplaceWithPrefab>();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        prefab = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Prefab", prefab, typeof(GameObject), false);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Replace"))
        {
            var selection = Selection.gameObjects;

            for (var i = selection.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                var selected = selection[i];
                var prefabType = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType(prefab);
                GameObject newObject;

                if (prefabType == PrefabType.Prefab)
                {
                    newObject = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(prefab);
                }
                else
                {
                    newObject = Instantiate(prefab);
                    newObject.name = prefab.name;
                }

                if (newObject == null)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Error instantiating prefab");
                    break;
                }

                Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(newObject, "Replace With Prefabs");
                newObject.transform.parent = selected.transform.parent;
                newObject.transform.localPosition = selected.transform.localPosition;
                newObject.transform.localRotation = selected.transform.localRotation;
                newObject.transform.localScale = selected.transform.localScale;
                newObject.transform.SetSiblingIndex(selected.transform.GetSiblingIndex());
                Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(selected);
            }
        }

        GUI.enabled = false;
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Selection count: " + Selection.objects.Length);
    }
}
```

any ideas for how i could save the informations?

Answer (score 0):

Unity recently added a tilemap system a few versions ago. It seems to be what you're looking for and it already handles the grids for you.

You can read more about it here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Tilemap.html

You can edit the tilemap with the SetTile method and a Tile object, rather than instanciating a bunch of prefabs. The Tiles themselves are created with a tile palette which you can also read more about in the page above.

Comment: unfortunately i need for 3d T.T